# How download Azure file storage in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, download, azure-storage

In application (Windows Phone 8) I need to download a Azure file storage. I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2014/09/24/upload-and-download-files-from-azure-storage.aspx), but that's about Universal Windows Apps.

I try this code:

```
    public async Task DownloadFile(string containerName, string code, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(code);
            //variant 1
            await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(code, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            // variant 2
            /*Stream data = await blockBlob.OpenReadAsync();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }*/


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

but there is no file download. How do I download a file? I have the URL of the file, maybe I just use `WebClient`?

Comment: why reverting the formatting change? @FetFrumos

Comment: I'm sorry - I deleted the other line. You can apply formatting changes

Comment: Rather than accessing directly, you could just wrap the object access in a WebAPI service.